# "I was working ON/WITH these tasks"

Tags: grammar

To write work report through an email, can I say:

> I was working **on** these tasks:
>
> 1. Something
> 2. Something
>    ...

Or should I say 'I was working **with** these tasks'...?

Comment: I was working on these tasks

Comment: But I'd probably use simple past:  *I worked on these tasks:*

Comment: To be frank though, your boss probably wants to know what you accomplished with respect to each of those tasks.  Instead of saying "I worked on building the bridge" you could say "I got the foundation poured and got 2 trusses constructed and am 25% complete on grading the western approach."

Comment: How about "work with questions"? @Jim

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng- How do you mean?  Last week I worked with Bob and Joe creating a video demonstrating our new product.  Last week I worked with some elderly patients helping them to rearrange some furniture in their rooms.  Last week I worked with oil paints and created two paintings- next week I plan to work with watercolors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the first form.  Working *with* is more appropriate when referring to *working with tools* or *working with friends*

Note:

*was working* is the **past continuous tense.**  To imply the work is complete, use the simple **past** tense.